# Wait for a valid sms code to be entered. After check it that, data Save to Databases php

Tags: php, laravel, api, sms, reset

hi I have some problem here  in my code
i want to save data in database after the user enter the sms code is send to his phone mobile

### i want to wait the proccess here and save data i don't want to lose it
after user enter sms code i save all data in database

```
public function registered(IdentityRequest $request) {
    $response = Http::get(route('fake') , [
        'national_id' => $request->input('national_id'),
        'date_birth' => $request->input('date_birth')
    ]);
    if($response['status'] == 200) {
        // i saved the data here 
        $userInformation = $response['data'];
    } else {
        return $this->returnErrorResponse('E002', 'no user ', '404');
    }
    // send OTP verification after validate request of user
    $otp = new Client(env('ENV_ACCOUNT_SID' , 'sid') , env('ENV_AUTH_TOKEN' , 'token));
    $smsCode = rand(100000, 999999);
    $message = $otp->messages->create("+".$request->input('phone') , [
        "body" => $smsCode, // this code i send to user
        "from" => "+11111"
    ]);
    // here i want to whit untill user enter the code and i don't want to lose data
    // from $request and $userInformation 
    // how i can do that
   // after the user enter valid code sms and i check it from him 
   // i saved all the data in database

}
```

Comment: It may be easier to store the values on the database but with some sort of unverified flag.  Once that valid code is entered, you can update the database to set the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not do that.

You have to do it in 2 phase and 4 step

1. Get the information from user, save it in a persistent storage like file or db
2. Send code via sms and save code along with user information
3. Send sms, and redirect user to another page, so he/she should fill a form with an email or national_id and the code that you sent to her/him
4. verify that code match with user information